# Checking if an NSUserDefaults key exists or not crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift

The following code is in my **AppDelegate** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:` method. When I try to  run the app, it crashes.

```
var accessToken = ""
if let key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("accesstoken"){
         accessToken = key as! String
        }
```

The only crash log I get from Xcode is:

[image]

I also have tried :

```
if  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("accesstoken") != nil {
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue ?

Comment: go to the line in code where it crashes and show us

Comment: You really shouldn't store your sensitive information in user defaults.

Comment: You apps isn't crash of above code. But crashing in another line. But xCode show bad and wrong.

Comment: It does not indicate any line in my code, console does not show anything except (lldb) as well

Comment: Change `objectForKey` to `stringForKey`

Comment: The thing is once i have set the value for key "accesstoken" manually , Then build the app it runs fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try optional casting

```
var accessToken:String? = nil
if let key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("accesstoken") as? String {
    accessToken = key
}
```

Comment: Of course, one would use `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accesstoken")` now